# How do I start taskgated again?

Tags: macos, daemons

I killed `taskgated` from the Activity Monitor and since then it is not been running. How do I start the process `taskgated` again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either reboot, or run

```
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist
```

Comment: and yet, taskgated is still not running!

Answer (score 5):

When I ran `launchctl load` I got this error:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist: Operation already in progress
```

So I had to run:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist
```

Followed by:

```
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist
```

And even then it took about a half minute for it to show up in `ps`.

Comment: Since El Capitan, you won't be able to unload the task while SIP (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) is engaged. You'll need to disable it (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) to perform this. Rebooting might be easier...

Answer (score 0):

Use this command without sudo. (Worked on Yosemite)

`launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist`